# Как оценивать стоимость разработки под Android начинающему фрилансеру?

Tags: android, фриланс

Как и по каким критериям оценивать стоимость разработки приложений под Android начинающему фрилансеру?

Допустим есть такое задание:

> Отправить запрос на сервер, получить ответ в виде json с данными по
>   товарам, пишем парсер, отображаем все в списке в виде RecyclerView и
>   CardView, каждый элемент списка имеет изображение, название и краткое
>   описание. По клику на элемент списка переходим на страницу с подробным
>   описанием товара, сдесь картинка, название, и полное описание
>   товара(если описание слишком большое оно скролиться) и кнопка по
>   нажатию просто переходим в web браузер по указанной ссылке. Ну и пусть
>   будет возможность добавлять товар в избранное, для этого нужно создать
>   базу данных SQLite и хранить там просто id выбранного товара, в Ui
>   помечаем избранный товар звездочкой. Ну и пусть будет какой то график
>   по определенному товару с какой то статистикой, данные для построения
>   графика так же получаем с сервера в виде json.

Вот такой пример. Как оценить приложение и по каким критериям? Спасибо.

Comment: Оценивайте по своему рейту (стоимость часа работы) и количества часов на выполнение задачи. Ваш пример довольно примитивен, так что на это тоже можно сделать по правку.

Answer (score 2):

Основной критерий это время - человеко-дни. Драйвером человеко-дней является количество экранов/виджетов фронтенда и/или бэкенд операций.

1. Чистой разработки здесь пара дней (считая, что сервер уже есть
   готовый и его не надо доводить до ума) - бэкенд здесь примитивный,
   так что 1 экран=1 день - справедливо считаю.
2. Плюс какие-ни какие усилия дизайнера (ну там цвета, стили, размеры) - ну 1/2 
   дня или может даже 1 день (максимум)
3. Сколько то дней на тестирование (возможно потребуется отдельная тестовая 
   среда, набор девайсов для теста). Я не знаю - зависит от требований 
   заказчика.

Дальше переводим человеко-дни на бабки, исходя из рыночных цен или жадности подрядчика.

Если подрядчик голодный кодер из Урюпинска - допускаю, что его человеко-день стоит несколько тысяч руб.

Если подрядчик какая нить корпорация со штаб-квартирой в BVI, то надо готовить от 200 (минимум) до 2000 вечнозеленых за 1 день.

Нормальный фрилансер, с хорошим опытом и портфолио сваяет все за $500, но потом замаешься бегать за поддержкой или спрашивать документацию.

---

*По роду своей основной деятельности я время от времени как раз рассчитываю стоимость работы кодеров/консультантов, я именно его и описал в своем ответе. Полагаю, что он излишне формализован, но именно так это работает. Тебе приносят ТЗ, который дербанится на фронтенд и бэкенд компоненты, далее приблизительно экспертно (а иногда и по справочникам) оцениваются трудозатраты в днях/часах. Далее часы/дни переводятся на денежки исходя из рынка, потом получается бюджет, далее тендер, выбор - примерно так.*

Comment: Производительность программистов (как и других работников), может различаться в разы и десятки раз (в зависимости от наличия опыта и мотивации и других факторов). Считаю ваш подход к оценке слишком "оптимистичным" - он подходит, если бы ТЗ дали вам, но бесполезен для многих остальных, в т.ч. топикстартеру (у которого 62 реп и вопрос об оценке трудозатрат). Тем не менее, вероятно лучше такой ответ, чем никакого.

Comment: Пара дней? Я думал тут разговор о паре часов

Comment: @PeterSamokhin за пару часов - ну давай, а кто за полчаса все сделает :)

Comment: @Kromster по роду своей основной деятельности я время от времени как раз рассчитываю стоимость работы кодеров/консультантов, я именно его и описал в своем ответе. Полагаю, что он излишне формализован, но именно так это работает. Тебе приносят ТЗ, который дербанится на фронтенд и бэкенд компоненты, далее приблизительно экспертно (а иногда и по справочникам) оцениваются трудозатраты в днях/часах. Далее часы/дни переводятся на денежки исходя из рынка, потом получается бюджет, далее тендер, выбор - примерно так.

Comment: @Barmaley возможно я что-то не так понимаю, но ТС спрашивает скорее всего о банальном фриланс-заказе, где никакой речи о дизайнерах и проч. не идёт, и вопрос стоит в том, как оценить непосредственно разработку самого приложения при всём остальном готовом. А уж сверстать два экрана — со списком и с отображением картинки и текста, я думаю, можно успеть и за 15 минут сделать.

Comment: @PeterSamokhin осталось еще дойти до 5 минут, а чего его жалеть то время :)

Я рассказал об общем подходе к расчету. Кстати, не учтено время на деплоймент и поддержку. Как правило, собственно разработка занимает не более 20% - все остальное уходит на тестирование, разворачивание и поддержку (понимаю, что для ТС это не актуально) - я просто привел общую практику - надеясь на то, что это интересно не только ТС...